# WPF DataGrid Master/Detail: How to show Master property within Detail that's within a different ItemSource

Tags: wpf, datagrid, master-detail

I have an object hierarchy of this: Orders have Allocations. My DataGrid has an ItemSource of Orders which then shows some details of each order in each grid row. Upon clicking on a grid row, a details pane comes up with additional details including a list of Allocations for each order. What I need to do is to somehow reference back to the Master record and pull a bit of detail (which would end up repeating) for each allocation. If I try to RelativeSource back to the DataGrid, I cannot refer to the property since that source is a whole collection and I need to get the value off of the item of that collection.

Below is a simplified version of the XAML I'm using. Basically, I need to bind to QuantityTypeDescription that's in the master record from each Allocation item in the child (Order) record.

```
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Trade" Binding="{Binding TransactionTypeDescription}" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Adjustment" Binding="{Binding QuantityTypeDescription}" Width="Auto"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!--Order Summary-->
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackPanel Background="DarkSlateGray" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TransactionTypeDescription}" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5,0,0,0" FontSize="14" Foreground="White"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Name="Name" Text="{Binding SecurityName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Background="DarkSlateGray"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Allocations}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
```

**NOTE: Here I need to get back up one level to get QuantityTypeDescription**

```
                                    <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=QuantityTypeDescription}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>-->
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Amount}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ElementName` Binding to refer to your main `DataGrid`'s `SelectedItem`

```
 <DataGrid Name="MainDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Trade" Binding="{Binding TransactionTypeDescription}" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Adjustment" Binding="{Binding QuantityTypeDescription}" Width="Auto"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!--Order Summary-->
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackPanel Background="DarkSlateGray" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TransactionTypeDescription}" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5,0,0,0" FontSize="14" Foreground="White"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Name="Name" Text="{Binding SecurityName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Background="DarkSlateGray"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Allocations}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MainDataGrid,Path=SelectedItem.QuantityTypeDescription}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Amount}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Boy, that seemed too darn obvious! I did quite a bit of searching before putting this question up here and I didn't think of the SelectedItem angle. Thank you, your solution works fine.